# Convert H2 sql query to JPQL

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2, jpql

I'm using H2 database in developpement, i wrote a native query, that supports only H2. I want now to convert it to JPQL, so i can use it in production mode.

Inside the query i'm using the DATE_ADD function, which adds a value from the database to the current date, i have tried to search the equivalent for JPQL, but i wasn't successful.

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(
        value = "UPDATE ORDER_TABLE O SET O.STATE='CANCELED' WHERE O.STATE='PENDING' AND DATEADD('HOUR',SELECT P.VALUE FROM PARAMETER P WHERE P.NAME ='PENDING_ORDER_TTL' , O.CREATED_AT) < NOW()",
        nativeQuery = true)
void updatePendingOrder();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the Date in Java:

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE Order o SET o.state='CANCELED'" + 
             " WHERE o.state='PENDING' AND o.createdAt < :cutOff")
@Modifying
//Date/LocalDate/LocalDateTime or whatever
public void updateOrders(@Param("cutOff") Date cutOff)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is it possible to do it inside the query ?

Comment: Well here are the supported functions and I don't see one to increment dates. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#JPQL_supported_functions